# Analyzing variables which are bound by [0,1] in R (and in general)

Tags: regression, econometrics

I'm compiling some data for econometrics research.

$Y$ is the dependent variable, which is a probability index (the Simpson Biological Diversity index): \begin{equation}D = 1- \sum  \frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{N(N-1)}\end{equation} and is bound by the range [0,1]

$X$ is the independent variable, which is the proportion of a particular subgroup which live in a given area $(n/N)$ which is also bound by the range [0,1].

When I run a scatter plot of these points, naturally they follow similar trends, but the conditional variances behave very differently. How can I account for this and analyze this in R?

Here's `y1~x1`: 
[image]
Here's `y2~x2:`
[image]

`x1` and `x2` are both different subgroups of the population in the unit of analysis, but obviously the distributions are behaving very differently in these two examples in particular. Would functional form transformation in the model work ($-x^2$) or is there are more precise procedure to use with variables like this?

Comment: In both cases I'd suggest taking a peek at a plot of $y^*=y/(1-x)$ vs $x^*=1-x$ and seeing how that looks.

Comment: More information about the *raw* data (both "independent" and dependent) would be interesting and useful. The most striking thing about these two plots (to me) is that they appear to have a sharp lower bound of $y=2x(1-x)$, suggesting all scatter consists of *nonnegative* additive error (with nonnegative expectation).

Comment: @whuber These plots are measuring the proportion of an census tract which is inhabited by a certain race/ethnicity against the diversity of that tract. The two examples I provided are x1='White % of population' and x2='African-American % of population'. Could you also elaborate on what you mean by "sharp lower bound' and the nonnegative additive errors?